# How to handle reletive path in awesome-wm

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

In my **'rc.lua'** file I currently have the following code:

```
naughty.notify({                                                                           
    preset = naughty.config.presets.info,                                               
    text = "MPC: Play!",                                                                   
    icon = "/home/user/.config/awesome/icons/mpd.png",                                                              
    icon_size = 20,                                                                       
    })
```

How can make the following icon path work, instead?

```
icon = "~/.config/awesome/icons/mpd.png",
```

Answer (score 3):

If awesome-wm does not have direct support for this, use

```
icon = os.getenv("HOME").."/.config/awesome/icons/mpd.png"
```

or

```
icon = string.gsub("~/.config/awesome/icons/mpd.png", "~", os.getenv("HOME"))
```

Comment: Any reason why `string.gsub` would be better than the direct `os.getenv("HOME")` approach? Expanding ~ in the middle of a path is wrong and I think the first version is more readable.

Comment: @UliSchlachter, I had things like this in mind: `path = ~/one/path:~/another/path`, but for an `icon` this is overkill.